# javascript - How do I reduce multiple Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise, reduce

I am trying to use a `Promise.all` inside of a `reduce` and cannot get my `function` to work, unless there is only one user in my array.  The starting object of the `reduce` is a `Promise`.  The first time through the `reduce`, the `Promise` has `.all` available on it.  The second time through, the `.all` is not available.

```
return UserQueries.addUsersOnCasefileCreate(input).then(users => {
  return users.reduce((promise, user) => {
    return promise.all([
      AddressQueries.addAddress(user.address, user.userId, input.orgId),
      EmailQueries.addEmail(user.emails, user.userId, input.orgId),
      PhoneQueries.addPhones(user.phones, user.userId, input.orgId)
    ])
    .then(() => Promise.resolve(user))
  }, Promise);
})
```

How could I perform this operation?

Comment: There's an obvious case typo between `promise` and `Promise`, anyway.

Comment: The `promise` that is lower case is just the first argument of the `reduce` referring to the `Promise` as the initial object.  It isn't a typo.

Comment: There is no `Promise.prototype.all()`. Only `Promise.all()`.

Comment: The `promise` from the first argument is the `Promise` in the initial object.  That is why it works the first time through the loop.  That is why `Promise.all` is available at first.

Comment: I doubt it. You're calling a nonexistent function.

Comment: Obviously you don't understand.  Move on to the next question.

Comment: @jhamm - no, you don't understand - there is no `Promise.prototype.all` - your code as written will fail with errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize with `Promise` which is a function, though return a resolved `Promise` object, where the two are not the same.

You can initialize with `Promise.resolve()`, call `promise.then()`, then return `Promise.all()` with `.then()` chained within first `.then()`, which passes `Promise` object to next iteration at `.reduce()`.

```
return UserQueries.addUsersOnCasefileCreate(input).then(users => {
  return users.reduce((promise, user) => {
    return promise.then(() => Promise.all([
      AddressQueries.addAddress(user.address, user.userId, input.orgId),
      EmailQueries.addEmail(user.emails, user.userId, input.orgId),
      PhoneQueries.addPhones(user.phones, user.userId, input.orgId)
    ]))
    .then(() => user))
  }, Promise.resolve());
})
```

Comment: I tried this, but I only get the last user in the result.  I don't get the rest of the users that are inserted.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't get the rest of the users that are inserted."? There is no need to use `.reduce()` if expected result is array of results. What is purpose for using `.reduce()`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `reduce()`. Just map the things and wait them all.

```
return UserQueries.addUsersOnCasefileCreate(input).then(users => {
  return Promise.all(users.map((user) => {
    return Promise.all([
      AddressQueries.addAddress(user.address, user.userId, input.orgId),
      EmailQueries.addEmail(user.emails, user.userId, input.orgId),
      PhoneQueries.addPhones(user.phones, user.userId, input.orgId)
    ]);
  }));
});
```